# Program force close

Tags: android, manifest

Here is my PlayerActivity:

```
 package player.org;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.MediaController;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class PlayerActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private MediaView media=new MediaView(this);
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(media);
    }
}
```

here is my MediaView:

```
    package player.org;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.content.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.graphics.Color;

    class MediaView extends View
            {
                public MediaView(Context context)
                    {
                        super(context);
                        setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    }





            }
```

and here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="player.org"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity 
        android:name=".MediaView"
        android:label="@string/MediaView_title">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".PlayerActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>
</manifest>
```

But when I Launch the app., It force closes.

Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks for your answers

Comment: Please post the logcat output ..

Comment: You can probably find some helpful information about why this happens by checking logcat. If you're using Eclipse, go to Window -> Show View -> Other -> Android -> Logcat. If not, open DDMS.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing this line `private MediaView media=new MediaView(this);`,before the Activity is initiated.So `'this'` keyword is force closing your application

Please use like this

```
 public class PlayerActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private MediaView media;
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(media);
      media=new MediaView(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answere, that's realy help

Comment: Your are welcome and i think upvoting/accepting is also the way of thanking